# ApplicationInsights - How to Track WebAPI Usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

I have been using ApplicationInsights for a couple of months now.
While it is great for MVC and Web applications in general, I have some WebAPI service applications that I'd like to track the usage for.

For example,  I have different RESTful APIs in my application and I'd like to see how many calls are made every day (or over a period of time) to compare usage.

The usage tab in ApplicationInsights seems to be tailor made for HTML Web Applications.

Is there a way to utilize it for services?

Comment: App Insights tracks *additional* information that may not apply to something like a Web Api, but you should have no issue tracking a Web Api. Is there some particular information you're missing? What is the actual issue here?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I am trying to track **usage**.  I can track requests with no issue.  But I need **usage**.  I want to be able to answer the question "How many users used X API over the past 72 hours?"

Comment: Isn't that the same thing? Requests are usage. Are you just looking for something like "uniques" in analytics parlance, i.e. unique users who made a request?

Comment: There's a "Usage" tab in App Insights, which tracks users, sessions and page views. Is this not available for your API?

Comment: @ChrisPratt The "**Usage**" tab does not show any data for my API.  That is my main issue.  For web applications, that tab seems to get its data directly from the client (browser).  But that is the only good view for what I want.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Yeah, the usage stats apparently come from a script you have to include in your HTML, so that pretty much precludes a Web Api from being able to make use of that particular feature. Looks like you're unfortunately just out of luck here. You'll need to find some other method to get that information.

Comment: Well, I take that back. You can look into the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-trace-logs. Maybe between the two you can come up with a way to track the information you need. Looks like it's a manual affair, though.

Comment: @IssaFram The **Usage** tab is built for page view, sessions, user related data and is unfortunately not applicable to a web API like you've already mentioned. Web apps directly use a piece of javascript to get all info. However for an API, the only would be to write your custom page view metrics, [`TelemetryClient.TrackPageView()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient.trackpageview?view=appinsights-2.3.0-beta3) but this doesn't seem very useful for an API

Comment: How do you identify unique users?

Comment: @BanksySan I am using Windows Authentication, so I don't think that should be a problem.

Comment: @IssaFram that would do the trick. Have you tried just adding the username to the telemetry object's context?

Comment: @BanksySan Application Insights automatically tracks all requests without me having to do anything extra. All out of the box. I think I have to use one of the track event methods in order for this to work. I can add username there, if need be.

Comment: @IssaFram did you get a chance to look at the answer?

Comment: @degant Yes, I looked at your answer.  I upvoted it for now.  I will **accept** as the answer once I have tested it out.  Should be in the next couple of days.  I appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, you want to determine usage of each API based on users. You already have request data available for every API but it cannot be filtered based on users since we aren't tracking users with every telemetry event.

If you want to filter telemetry data (requests, exceptions etc.) based on users or any property, you would need it to be available in the properties of the telemetry event so that you can directly filter it and generate charts in the metrics explorer. To do this you can create a `TelemetryInitializer`.

Telemetry initializers allow you to add global properties along with all your telemetry data which means it will be executed for all telemetry events that are sent from your app. Here's an example for tracking UserID along with every telemetry event. I'm assuming that the `User.Identity` will be set for you since you are using Windows Authentication. This will also work for any other authentication (Azure AD, certificate based authentication etc) too as long as the `IPrinicipal` is set in the Http Request.

```
public class UserTelemetryIntitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        if (context == null)
            return;

        // If user has authenticated, add a property UserID to telemetry which will have
        //  * domain\\username for Windows Authentication
        //  * username@domain.com for Azure AD Authentication
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            telemetry.Context.Properties["UserID"] = context.User.Identity.Name;
        else
            telemetry.Context.Properties["UserID"] = "Null";
    }
}
```

Don't forget to load your telemetry initializer, using `ApplicationInsights.config`:

```
<ApplicationInsights>
  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <!-- Fully qualified type name, assembly name: -->
    <Add Type="MvcWebApp.Telemetry.UserTelemetryIntitializer, MvcWebApp"/>
    ...
  </TelemetryInitializers>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

Alternatively, you could also load the initializer using code *instead*. In your `global.asax.cs` or `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers
        .Add(new UserTelemetryIntitializer());
}
```

You can read more about Telemetry Initializers [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling.md#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer).

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this.  You don't need a custom property for UserID, but it all works out in the end regardless.

Comment: Know this is old, but as Issa said, you can just use this: `telemetry.Context.User.Id = your_user_id`. This ensures the correct property is set and shown in the Portal.

Comment: Why `telemetry.Context.Properties["UserID"] = "Null";` if user no authenticated?

Comment: @jpgrassi when no user authenticated, instead of set `"NULL"` shouldn't I set some random like `New.Guid()`?